# How to copy string by clicking on string?

Tags: php, jquery

How can I copy string by clicking on string. I have URL field which contain very long string in my table so I am showing that string by on 30 character.
ex.
Full string like "https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how+to+copy+text+by+click+on+text+in+php"

And I am showing like "https://www.google.co.in/webhp...."

So when I clicked on that string. I want to copy that full string so I can paste it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try **clipboard.js** (https://clipboardjs.com/).

And with this library you can add link with special `data-clipboard-text` attribute. From documentation:

> Truth is, you don't even need another element to copy its content
>   from. You can just include a data-clipboard-text attribute in your
>   trigger element.

So you can add element with text `https://www.google.co.in/webhp....` and set `data-clipboard-text` to your full URL that you want to copy.

You can use it simply by adding this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    new Clipboard('.trigger');
})
```

**Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/636hzm3z/).**

Comment: Browser support for manipulating the clipboard is patchy. Clipboard.js provides a nice work around in that there is a callback if copying to the clipboard fails. When it's not supported, you can use that callback to add an html message containing the full url, which can be manually selected and copied.

Comment: Here's the documentation on that: https://clipboardjs.com/#browser-support - looks like it's just Safari that doesn't support it. Anyway my point is that clipboard.js provides graceful downgrade options

Comment: @alexanderbird, good point! It's a really great workaround, thanks for that information!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link 
https://brooknovak.wordpress.com/2009/07/28/accessing-the-system-clipboard-with-javascript/

It's different between browsers when accessing the clipboard.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('a.my_link').click(function() {
        link = $(this).attr('href');
        // Copy link to clipboard

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

And your link in the html

```
<a href="fulllink">Partial Link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your nice effort. But It is not what i want. have a good day  :)